# He is there. / There he is

Tags: phrase-meaning

Could you please explain me the difference between:

> **He is there.**

> **There he is.**

As I understand it, both phrases are used: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He%20is%20there%2CThere%20he%20is&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&case_insensitive=on&corpus=15&smoothing=50&direct_url=t4%3B%2CHe%20is%20there%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhe%20is%20there%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHe%20is%20there%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CThere%20he%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthere%20he%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThere%20he%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20He%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThere%20He%20is%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2CHe%20is%20there%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhe%20is%20there%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHe%20is%20there%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CThere%20he%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthere%20he%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThere%20he%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20He%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThere%20He%20is%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: "There he is!" is usually an *exclamation* (speaker expressing surprise on becoming aware that "he" is nearby). Whereas "He is there" is more likely a response (perhaps accompanied by pointing) to the question "Where is he?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'He (or she) is there' simply states that someone is at a place, but 'there he (or she) is' is drawing someone's attention to the fact that someone is somewhere visible, possibly after looking for that person. Often accompanied by a pointing gesture, and also often followed by an exclamation mark.